# Download Interactive maps data to csv

Tags: maps, interactive

I'm looking at an interactive map (https://gis.hennepin.us/property/map/default.aspx) and I want to download all the data on the map.

You normally click on the map and it returns info in a window just for the location you clicked on. How can I get all the information on the map in one go?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy, if the data isnt locked.

1. Open the inspector
2. Go to networks (refresh site)
3. then on the upper bar you can select the type of data you want to be shown.